# Map Java Boolean to bit in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, jpa, boolean, bit

I am trying to map a Boolean variable in java with a bit column (nullible )in SQL Server. I can see the record getting updated in DB but the status value is not updated . Do i need to change the data type to anything else . please suggest.

My pojo element looks like below.

```
@Column(name = "status")
@Override
public Boolean getStatus() {
    return super.getStatus();
}
```

Comment: Well a bit a not the same as a boolean. You even mention that it is NULLable in your table. This means it have can three values in the database (0, 1, NULL). You would have to check the value and return false if 0, true if 1. No idea what you want to do if it is NULL. Do you equate that to True or False? Not sure if java has a nullable boolean datatype or not.

Comment: @Sean Lange I am trying to save the value from frontend to the db. the reason i kept it nullable so that all the existing record dont get impacted

Comment: Gotcha. So going forward you won't have NULL. Not sure how it works in java but you need to get either the string "True/False" or 1/0 to send to the database.

Comment: @SeanLange, Boolean with a capital B is nullable, boolean lowercase is a primitive with only discrete values.